# Why does a for-loop in VBA loop one less time when using bounds in the ten-thousandths place?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, decimal

While working on a function in VBA, I noticed that sometimes during my tests I would get different results from when I ran the same function with different parameters. I wrote the following sub to try to figure out what was going on.

When the `for-loop` is executed with bounds in the thousandths place, it loops through the `for` statements 3 times, as I expect it to. Here, the immediate window generously prints a "3" for me:

```
Const vStart = 0.001
Const vStep = 0.001
Const vStop = 0.003

Sub LoopThru()
    Dim myVar As Double
    Dim counter As Integer 

    For myVar = vStart To vStop Step vStep
        counter = counter + 1
    Next myVar

    Debug.Print counter
End Sub
```

When I reduce the bounds and step by a magnitude, however, the `for-loop` only executes the `for` statements twice.

```
Const vStart = 0.0001
Const vStep = 0.0001
Const vStop = 0.0003

Sub LoopThru()
    Dim myVar As Double
    Dim counter As Integer

    For myVar = vStart To vStop Step vStep
        counter = counter + 1
    Next myVar

    Debug.Print counter
End Sub
```

In my actual project, I'm creating a large 3D array of values as a lookup table. Since the first dimension of the array has to be generated using Solver, I will greatly reduce the application's runtime by creating this lookup table instead of having to recalculate using Solver over and over again while the application is running.

Since it is a 3D array, there are 3 nested for loops, the second of which may range through values from the hundred-thousandths to the tenths place.

Perhaps a `do-while loop` is more fitting for this situation - in fact I'm rewriting the code now to use a while loop instead. Or a conditional set of `for-loops`. Either way, **I would like to know the best solution for this problem, as well as why there is a difference in the number of loops executed depending on the magnitude of the bounds in these `for loops`.**

Comment: What happens if you explicitly declare the constants 'As Double'? I'm thinking casting or rounding from the implicit initialised type to Double in your loop may be tripping-up somewhere.

Comment: The reason for your troubles with the `For` loop is due to float point precission (or lack of).  [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7330887/445425) for an explanation.  You will need to use `Long` type for your loop counter.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru, I tried declaring the constants as `Doubles`, but to no avail. @chris, I had also tried to declare the loop counter (`myVar`) as `Long`, but the `Long` variable type is an integer, so I just got an overflow. The help menu also turned me on to the variable type `vbDecimal`, which I attempted but that didn't work either. Maybe a package is missing?

Comment: The root of your issue is floating point precission, and the rounding that results from it.  You _will_ need to reacst your loop counter to `Long`  Changing to a different floating point data type doesn't solve the underlying issue.  If you need help with that, add more details to your Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the limited precission that can be stored in a floating point variable.
For a complete explanation you shoud read the paper *"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"*, by David Goldberg, published in the March, 1991 issue of Computing Surveys.

[Link to paper](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

In VBA the default floating point type is Double which is a IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point number.

You will need to refactor your code to use an integer type fro the loop counter.

To demonstrate one way to convert to integer loop counter, consider this:

```
Const vStart = 0.0001
Const vStep = 0.0001
Const vStop = 0.0003

Sub LoopThru()
    Dim myVar As Double
    Dim counter As Long

    For counter = 0 To (vStop - vStart) * 10000 Step vStep * 10000
        myVar = counter * vStep + vStart
        Debug.Print "Iteration " & counter, "myVar = " & myVar
    Next
End Sub
```

How you will need to implement in your wider context will depend on your specific situation.

Since you mention you are looping over arrays, consider using something like

```
For i = LBound(YourArray, n) to UBound(YourArray, n)
```

where `n` = the array dimension to loop