# How to remove zero's appearing at the end of number

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Using Microsoft Office Excel 2007, I have to insert the numbers of more than 15 digits in a cell. But I have a problem inserting the complete number because the cell is automatically displaying zero's after 15 digits:

[image]

Comment: The reason is the limited precision that can be stored in floating point numbers.  [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7330887/445425)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel uses 15 significant digits in calculation so, logically, it can't display more than that - any digits beyond the 15th will be displayed as zero.