# VBA - Inconsistent Condition Evaluation

Tags: excel, while-loop, vba

Inconsistent Condition Evaluation
Sometimes the `While`loop executes one extra time when the condition should evaluate `False`.
Example, if I enter 1 as a start, 3 as end and 0.05 as step.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim StrPrompt As String
Dim StepValue As Double
Dim StartValue As Double
Dim EndValue As Double
Dim CurrentValue As Double

StrPrompt = "Enter a Positive start number."
redo:
StartValue = Application.InputBox(StrPrompt, "Start", , , , , , Type:=1)
If Not (StartValue >= 0) Then
    StrPrompt = "Please enter a postive number."
    GoTo redo
End If

MsgBox "User entered " & StartValue, , "Start Value"
Cells(1, 4) = StartValue & " Start"


StrPrompt = "Enter a Positive end number."
redo1:
EndValue = Application.InputBox(StrPrompt, "End", , , , , , Type:=1)
If EndValue <= StartValue Then
    StrPrompt = "Please enter a number larger than start number."
    GoTo redo1
End If

MsgBox "User entered " & EndValue, , "End Value"
Cells(1, 4) = EndValue & " End"

StrPrompt = "Enter a Positive step value."
redo2:
StepValue = Application.InputBox(StrPrompt, "Step", , , , , , Type:=1)
If Not (StepValue > 0) Then
    StrPrompt = "Please enter a number > 0."
    GoTo redo2
End If


MsgBox "User entered " & StepValue, , "Step Value"
Cells(1, 4) = StartValue & " Step"

CurrentValue = StartValue
Cells(1, 4) = CurrentValue

   While CurrentValue < EndValue

   ' MsgBox "Current Value before increment " & CurrentValue, , "Before"
    CurrentValue = CurrentValue + StepValue
    'MsgBox "Current Value after increment " & CurrentValue, , "After"
    Cells(1, 4) = CurrentValue
   Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: We need more information. With the inputs as stated in your question what then is placed into `Cells(1, 4)` in each loop iteration?

Comment: 1, 1.05, 1.10.....then ends at 3.05

Comment: floating point precision limitations can cause this type of error.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7330887/445425)

Comment: consider hitting your WHILE conditions with ROUND().

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix the issue, although it seems a bit crazy that such small numbers trips up Excel.