# Why do VBA and Excel disagree on whether two cells are equal?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I am trying to compare two cells in a table:

[image: Table]

The column "MR" is calculated using the formula `=ABS([@Value]-A1)` to determine the moving range of the column "Value". The values in the "Value" column are not rounded. The highlighted cells in the "MR" column (B3 and B4) are equal. I can enter the formula `=B3=B4` into a cell and Excel says that B3 is equal to B4.

But when I compare them in VBA, VBA says that B4 is greater than B3. I can select cell B3 and enter the following into the Immediate Window `? selection.value = selection.offset(1).value`. That statement evaluates to false.

I tried removing the absolute value from the formula thinking that might have had something to do with it, but VBA still says they aren't equal.

I tried adding another row where Value=1.78 so MR=0.18. Interestingly, the MR in the new row (B5) *is* equal to B3, but is *not* equal to B4.

I then tried increasing the decimal of A4 to match the other values, and now VBA says they *are* equal. But when I added the absolute value back into the formula, VBA again says they are *not* equal. I removed the absolute value again and now VBA is saying they are *not* equal.

Why is VBA telling me the cells are not equal when Excel says they are? How can I reliably handle this situation through VBA going forward?

Comment: The vba issue will be caused by [limited floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330887/445425).  Excel formula do a better job of it than vba

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) for how Excel differs from vba

Comment: @chrisneilsen While the question you linked to is for a problem that is also caused by floating point numbers, the nature of the problems and answers are different. More notably, the answers in the linked question did not answer my question. And while the paper you linked in the answer and the article you linked in your comment were both informative, neither lead me to an answer regarding how to properly compare floating point numbers for equality.

Comment: sorry, but IMHO the answer to "how to properly compare floating point numbers for equality" _is_ contained in the linked dup (actually in the linked paper) and it's "Don't".  I see you've accepted Excel Hero's answer (and thats fine).  Everything contained in that answer is also contained in Goldbergs paper (which Excel Hero also links you to).  The "Solution" Excel Hero has offerd is "Don't compare for equality, compare for near equality", and rightly points out it's not a one size fits all solution (also noted in Goldbergs paper).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the [IEEE 754 Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is imprecise by design. Virtually every programming language suffers because of this.

IEEE 754 is an extremely complex topic and when you study it for months and you believe you understand fully, you are simply fooling yourself!

[Accurate floating point value comparisons](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/assertions.md#floating-point-comparisons) are difficult and error prone. Think long and hard before attempting to compare floating point numbers!

The Excel program gets around the issue by cheating on the application side. VBA on the other hand follows the IEEE 754 spec for [Double Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (***binary64***) faithfully.

A Double value is represented in memory using 64 bits. These 64 bits are split into three distinct fields that are used in binary scientific notation:

1. The SIGN bit (1 bit to represent the sign of the value: pos/neg)
2. The EXPONENT (11 bits, biased in value by +1023)
3. The MANTISSA (53 bits, 52 bits stored + 1 bit implied)

The mantissa in this system leverages the fact that all binary numbers begin with a digit of `1` and so that `1` is not stored in the bit-pattern. It is implied, increasing the mantissa precision to 53-bits for normal values.

The math works like this: **Stored Value = SIGN VALUE * 2^UNBIASED EXPONENT * MANTISSA**

Note that a stored value of `1` for the sign bit denotes a negative SIGN VALUE (-1) while a `0` denotes a positive SIGN VALUE (+1). The formula is `SIGN VALUE = (-1) ^ (sign bit)`.

The problem always boils down to the same thing.

> The vast majority of *[real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)* cannot be expressed precisely
> within this system which introduces small rounding errors that propagate
> like weeds.

It may help to think of this system as a grid of regularly spaced points. The system can represent ONLY the point-values and NONE of the real numbers between the points. All values assigned to a float will be rounded to one of the point-values (usually the closest point, but there are modes that enforce rounding upwards to the next highest point, or rounding downwards). Conducting any calculation on a floating-point value virtually guarantees the resulting value will require rounding.

To accent the obvious, there are an ***infinite*** number of real numbers between adjacent representable point-values on this grid; ***and all of them are rounded*** to the discreet grid-points.

To make matters worse, the gap size doubles at every Power-of-Two as the grid expands away from true zero (in both directions). For example, the gap length between grid points for values in the range of `2` to `4` is twice as large as it is for values in the range of `1` to `2`. When representing values with large enough magnitudes, the grid gap length becomes massive, but closer to true zero, it is miniscule.

With your example numbers...

---

`1.24` is represented with the following binary:

Sign bit = 0

Exponent = 01111111111

Mantissa = 0011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111

The Hex pattern over the full 64 bits is precisely: 3FF3D70A3D70A3D7.

The precision is derived exclusively from the 53-bit mantissa and the exact decimal value from the binary is:
0.2399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375

In this instance a leading integer of `1` is implied by the hidden bit associated with the mantissa and so the complete decimal value is:

1.2399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375

Now notice that this is not precisely `1.24` and that is the entire problem.

---

Let's examine `1.42`:

Sign bit = 0

Exponent = 01111111111

Mantissa = 0110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000

The Hex pattern over the full 64 bits is precisely: 3FF6B851EB851EB8.

With the implied `1` the complete decimal value is stored as:

1.4199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875000

And again, not precisely `1.42`.

---

Now, let's examine `1.6`:

Sign bit = 0

Exponent = 01111111111

Mantissa = 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010

The Hex pattern over the full 64 bits is precisely: 3FF999999999999A.

> Notice the repeating binary fraction in this case that is truncated
> and ***rounded*** when the  mantissa bits run out? Obviously 1.6 when
> represented in binary base2 can never be precisely accurate in the
> same way as 1/3 can never be accurately represented in decimal base10
> (0.33333333333333333333333... ≠ 1/3).

With the implied `1` the complete decimal value is stored as:

1.6000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250

Not exactly `1.6` but closer than the others!

---

Now let's subtract the full ***stored*** double precision representations:

`1.60` - `1.42` = 0.18000000000000015987

`1.42` - `1.24` = 0.17999999999999993782

So as you can see, they are not equal at all.

The usual way to work around this is [threshold testing](https://www.reidatcheson.com/floating%20point/comparison/2019/03/20/floating-point-comparison.html), basically an inspection to see if two values are close enough... and that depends on you and your requirements. Be forewarned, effective threshold testing is ***way*** harder than it appears at first glance.

Here is a function to help you get started comparing two Double Precision numbers. It handles many situations well but not all because no function can.

```
Function Roughly(a#, b#, Optional within# = 0.00001) As Boolean
    Dim d#, x#, y#, z#
    
    Const TINY# = 1.17549435E-38    'SINGLE_MIN
    
    If a = b Then Roughly = True: Exit Function
            
    x = Abs(a): y = Abs(b): d = Abs(a - b)
    
    If a <> 0# Then
        If b <> 0# Then
            z = x + y
            If z > TINY Then
                Roughly = d / z < within
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Roughly = d < within * TINY
End Function
```

The idea here is to have the function return `True` if the two Doubles are Roughly the same Within a certain margin:

```
MsgBox Roughly(3.14159, 3.141591)           '<---dispays True
```

The Within margin defaults to 0.00001, but you can pass whatever margin you need.

And while we know that:

```
MsgBox 1.60 - 1.42 = 1.42 - 1.24            '<---dispays False
```

Consider the utility of this:

```
MsgBox Roughly(1.60 - 1.42, 1.42 - 1.24)    '<---dispays True
```

---

@chris neilsen linked to an interesting [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) about Excel and IEEE 754.

And please read David Goldberg's seminal [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It changed the way I understood floating point numbers.

Comment: Why do use #'s when you declare your variable names? Great answer btw.

Comment: @JeremyThompson The `#` is the shortcut for Double type declaration. `Dim a#` is equivalent to `Dim a As Double`. Variable type declaration through symbols is actually the original way and goes back to the 1970s for the BASIC influenced languages. I've been programming since the 1970s and I prefer the succinctness.

Comment: FWIW, I've made an improved version of your `Roughly` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68291403/6609896), which I think people will find useful. It accounts for absolute differences like yours but also relative ones too, as well as special cases like +/- inf, but remaining quite optimised.