# Excel decimal fractions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can someone explain why these anomalies occur with the same arithmetic operation in excel?

1. =SUM(123.45,56.78,-180.23) returns **2.8421709430404E-14**
2. = 123.45+56.78-180.23 returns **0**

I would like to understand the logic behind these calculations. Please share some relevant resources.

Comment: You can add this to your question: if you put your three numbers in three cells (like typically A1:A3) and you ask for the sum of those cells, you get zero!

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores and processes numbers as floating point 64 bit numbers.  Because of the finite number of bits used, many (most) numbers are not precisely represented. This is the cause of the slightly wrong result of many calculations (Floating Point Precision has been addressed on Stack Overflow many times, eg [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330665/vba-rounding-problem/7330887#7330887) )

Excels' representation of numbers is described in this [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

This link includes

> Microsoft Excel was **designed around** the IEEE 754 specification to determine how it stores and calculates floating-point numbers

It explains Excel is based on but not completely faithful to IEEE 754.
It goes on to describe how imprecision occurs. It also explains several differences to the IEEE 754 standard, including

> Example when a value reaches zero
> In Excel 95 or earlier, enter the following into a new workbook:
>
> A1: =1.333+1.225-1.333-1.225
>
> Right-click cell A1, and then click Format Cells. On the Number tab, click Scientific under Category. Set the Decimal places to 15.
>
> Instead of displaying 0, Excel 95 displays -2.22044604925031E-16.
>
> Excel 97, however, **introduced an optimization** that attempts to correct for this problem. Should an addition or subtraction operation result in a value at or very close to zero, Excel 97 and later will compensate for any error introduced as a result of converting an operand to and from binary. The example above when performed in Excel 97 and later correctly displays 0 or 0.000000000000000E+00 in scientific notation.

The existence of this optimisation explains the OPs observed behaviour. Unfortunately it does not explain when the optimisation does and does not get applied.

Some examples based on OPs formula

[image]