# How to convert double to 'long double' as standard

Tags: c++

How to convert `double` to `long double` as C++ standard. I think just casting like this is not the right way?

```
double value = 1.2;
long double newValue = (long double)value;
```

Comment: That will give you a long double containing the specified value (but beware  that compilers are allowed to implement `double` and `long double` as the same type, and some do so).

Comment: off topic, but is there a processor that supports long double natively?

Comment: @thang: Yes--x86 does (for one example). It supports 32-bit (float), 64-bit (double) and 80-bit (long double) types in hardware.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, you're right.  I totally missed it.  Seems Intel wants to get rid of it though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206101/extended-80-bit-double-floating-point-in-x87-not-sse2-we-dont-miss-it.

Comment: @thang: more or less, yeah. They certainly want to get rid of x87 (stack based processor, so using all registers was difficult), and haven't included 80-bit types in the SSE instruction sets.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert as C++ standard"?

Answer (score 6):

That will work fine, but it will not magically create extra precision in `newValue`. That is, it will not produce the same result as:

```
long double newValue = 1.2L;
```

which will set `newValue` to a closer approximation to 1.2.

Comment: what do you think `about type` cast Vs `static cast` (your answer vs Evgenij Malashkin answer). which one is the C++ way?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: casting double to long double is an exact widening cast (because every `double` value is representable as a `long double`). Consequently, it is almost never necessary to cast, and my interpretation of the "C++ way" is that implicit casts are preferred in this case. If an explicit cast is required, I would normally use constructor syntax (`double(foo+3)`), but that's not possible with `long double` unless the `long double` is parenthesized, in which case it becomes a C-style cast `(long double)(foo+3)`, and that's how I would write it (but only if it was really necessary.)

Answer (score 4):

The standards guarantee that a `long double` can support all the values that a `double` can (or, to put it another way, the set of values a `double` can support is a subset of what a `long double` can represent).

So, the assignment

```
long double newValue = value;
```

is sufficient, albeit involving an implicit conversion of `value` from `double` to `long double` rather than an explicit conversion.   It is a conversion that does not lose precision.

Explicit alternatives in C++ are

```
long double newValue = (long double)value;    // as in original question
long double newvalue = static_cast<long double>(value);
```

It is really a matter of subjective style which alternative is considered better, because they all achieve the same effect without potential loss of precision.

Note that, if going the other way (converting from `long double` to `double`) it is often preferable to use an explicit conversion, since the conversion potentially loses precision (and can therefore change the value) - which is why compilers often (can be configured to) give warnings on such implicit conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Employ static_cast:

```
long double newValue = static_cast<long double>(value);
```

Or in C++11 style:

```
auto newValue = static_cast<long double>(value);
```

(known as "explicitly typed initializer idiom").