# visual studio 2015 exp results differ

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, exp

I have a c++ code in visual studio 2015 c++11.  The code  does EXP of

```
val = 7.3526137268510955991

double myCalulatedEXP= EXP(val);
//Lets print
std::cout.precision(20);
std::cout<<myCalulatedEXP;
```

On one machine I get  **1560.269320753015**3359 and on the other, I get **1560.269320753015**1085
See that last 4 digits does not match causing trouble for me. 
Though the difference is small it multiplies and adds up to a bigger difference later on.

Both machines have same processor identifier .

```
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
```

Both machines have same OS via

```
 `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"`


OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
OS Version:                6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
```

Both are windows server 2012 machines. I ran dependency walker to check if they are having different dlls versions linked . Both are exactly the same .

Please suggest

1) What can cause such differences?

2) How can I avoid such differences?

3) If processor, OS, dlls are the same can I still expect different results

Comment: Looks like you're good out to 16 digits. Double is generally only good out to 15 digits so you're doing pretty good. I don't think there is much of anything you can do.

Comment: Is the exact same executable running on both machines?

Comment: If these are 64-bit double precision then there are only 15.95 decimal digits plus the exponent - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: code updated inline .. yes exactly the same exe and same dlls

Comment: Point is if processor, OS, dlls are same can i still expect different results ?

Comment: Using `double` you only have 16 digits of accuracy per number, and lose even than if the magnitude of numbers differs enough in a chain of multiple operations.  The digits beyond the 16 are garbage, random, undefined, noise.

Comment: @DaveS still there is no random generator involved. I would expect on the same platform the same code compiled with the same compiler will produce the same results, even beyond defined precision for doubles. I would also be wondering why the bit pattern is different.

Comment: Look at the IEEE format at wiki.  A double only holds 53 binary digits / 15.95  decimal digits, period. It just can't store more than that.  If you are viewing more digits than that you're viewing some other junk from who knows where.

Comment: The CPU floating point registers on x86_64 CPUs are 80 bits unless SSE /SIMD is being used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206101/extended-80-bit-double-floating-point-in-x87-not-sse2-we-dont-miss-it

Comment: But once you stuff that into a `double` you lose the extra bits, and if you then print the `double` they don't magically re-attach themselves.

Comment: Dave, that fuzz should still be representative of the binary pattern stored. I can't think of a good reason for it to be different for the two numbers given the same hardware and the same code. I just don't think I can guarantee it. Mag, print out some hexfloat  (`printf("%a, doubleval);` because I can't guarantee `cout << hexfloat <<doubleval;` will work right) and see what's actually being stored That said, when you start performing math counting on that fuzz at the end you're in for disappointment. Somehow or other it's going to get you.

Comment: Maybe there is some bug (undefined behavior) in your EXP(). That could explain why identical hardware and executable executes differently.

Comment: Please also edit the question to show us your cout or printf so we can see the  formatting that generated the numbers above.

Comment: @user4581301 I was guessing that whatever the printf or cout code is might be pulling in garbage from adjacent memory, for example if it treated the double as an intel 80-bit float.

Comment: print is done via cout. Now Added in question

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IEEE 754 binary format for a `double` it is: 53 significant binary bits / 15.95 significant decimal digits plus 11 exponent bits.  (wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

This means if you print the `double` using a format that shows more than 16 significant digits, the extra digits may be garbage.

Not always, for example %.20f might be perfectly accurate if the exponent of the number is -4.

53 bits of accuracy is the best case.  A chain of operation on numbers of different magnitudes can lose accuracy, for example (1.23 e+20) + (0.45 e-30).

```
std::cout.precision(20);
```

Since a `double` has a maximum accuracy of 16 digits, this may include undefined digits.

This question's top answer suggests using 17 digits: [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Additional notes in the comments point to  Theorem 15 in this abstract of *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*, by David Goldberg - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: can i ensure with some means that extra digits are always 0 ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just set the precision lower, to 16 or 17?  See added information above.

Comment: cout is used to determine the area where the problem starts.  actually, mine is a mathematical application where a lot of matrix multiplication is happening along with tan sin and exp operations. unfortunately, on 2 machines, I get different results. so i printed where the problem starts .  initally i got no difference just difference in results . so i increased precision to determine where the problem originated. hence i used 20 precision .

Comment: You might just be expecting more accuracy than double precision is capable of.   In my `(1.23 e+20) + (0.45 e-30)` example above, the second number's contribution is simply lost.  That's one reason why Numerical Analysis exists as a field, to tell you what to expect.  It also comes up with methods to mitigate accuracy loss.